# Control.Parallel compile issue in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, compiler-errors, parallel-processing, ghc

The compiler is complaining each time on different example applications of parallel Haskell; with this message:

```
Could not find module `Control.Parallel.Strategies'
```

The ghc compiler command:

```
ghc -threaded -i/sudo/dir/par-modules/3 -cpp -DEVAL_STRATEGIES -eventlog --make parFib.hs
```

Same with simpler

```
ghc -O2 --make -threaded parFib.hs
```

What detail am I overlooking? Am I missing some PATH variable.

Imports can look like this:

```
module Main where
import System
#  if defined(EVAL_STRATEGIES)
import Control.Parallel
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
#endif
```

Cheers

Comment: The official [Haskell in 5 Steps tutorial](https://wiki.haskell.org/Haskell_in_5_steps) uses the `paralell` package.  I wonder why they don't mention anything about needing to install it?!  Your question helped me resolve confusion there, so thank you for asking it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You must install the [parallel](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel) package from Hackage. In most sane setups, this should be as simple as typing

```
cabal install parallel # note: not sudo cabal install parallel!
```

at your command prompt.

Comment: Could you also explain how the moon got there? =) cabal did the trick, thanks!

Comment: @gorn At some point in Earth's early history, a rogue planet, larger than Mars, struck the Earth in a great, glancing blow. Instantly, most of the rogue body and a sizable chunk of Earth were vaporized. The cloud rose to above 13,700 miles (22,000 kilometers) altitude, where it condensed into innumerable solid particles that orbited the Earth as they aggregated into ever larger moonlets, which eventually combined to form the moon. [source](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2004/07/0714_040714_moonfacts.html) =)

Answer (score 4):

I'm adding a new answer (instead of a comment) for visibility reasons.

After trying Daniel's answer, I still wasn't able to do `import Control.Parallel`, neither from `ghci`, nor with the compiler. The install command returned a warning message like this:

```
➜  ~ cabal install parallel
Resolving dependencies...
Up to date
Warning: You asked to install executables, but there are no executables in
target: parallel. Perhaps you want to use --lib to install libraries instead.
```

What ultimately resolved the issue was:

```
cabal install --lib parallel
```

Answer (score 2):

Like Daniel said, you'll need the parallel package. However if you'd prefer to use your system's package manager (which some people think you [should](http://ivanmiljenovic.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/repeat-after-me-cabal-is-not-a-package-manager/)), you can.

Note that, at least in the Fedora repos, you'll need ghc-parallel-devel, not just ghc-parallel to build.

```
#yum install ghc-parallel-devel
```