# How to install and import a library in haskell?

Tags: haskell

In official tutorial [Haskell in 5 steps](https://wiki.haskell.org/Haskell_in_5_steps), an example imports a library:

```
import Control.Parallel
```

Then I use ghc to compile:

```
ghc parallel.hs -o parallel -O2 --make -threaded -rtsopts
```

just as the tutorial tells me to do. (My filename is parallel.hs) But I got:

```
parallel.hs:1:1: error:
Could not find module ‘Control.Parallel’
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
1 | import Control.Parallel
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then I stackoverflowed it and find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575886/control-parallel-compile-issue-in-haskell). So I:

```
cabal new-install parallel --lib
```

And get:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Up to date
```

Then I compiled it again, but got the same error.
How to solve this? Did I miss any command line arguments?

---

Well, after `cabal install parallel`, the library is imported, the program is compiled successfully, and runs as expected.

I'll refer to documentations of cabal about the difference between `install` and `new-install`

Comment: What if you run this in verbose mode? So `-v`? Then it should show the list of packages it has searched through.

Comment: Not sure what the difference is, but I usually run `cabal install` without the `new-`. Just tried and it worked?

Comment: My cabal version is 2.4.1.0. It asked me to switch to new-install instead of using legacy v1 style command.

Comment: It works after `cabal install`, but new errors raise.

Comment: You can save yourself some future hurt if you learn and use `stack` now.

Comment: The current status quo is a bit weird. We now can install things using `cabal install`, `cabal new-install`, and `stack install`. Then we might have a package installed system-wide, user-local, or in some even more local sandbox. It can easily get messy. I now tend to do everything using `stack`, since the community seems to be slowly going in that direction. It could be simpler, though.

Comment: @chi the plan is actually that there will be only two options: `cabal new-install` (which will then be called simply `cabal install`) and `stack install`. No sandboxes or anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Lorenzo noted, `cabal install` works fine.  With `cabal new-install` you should have seen a warning that you forgot `--lib` since `parallel` does not include an executable and libraries must be explicitly installed via `--lib`.  The full set of functional commands are:

```sh
cd $(mktemp -d)
cabal update && cabal new-install --lib parallel
cat <<EOF > parallel.hs
module P where
import Control.Parallel
EOF
ghc -c parallel.hs
ls parallel.o parallel.hi
```

Yielding:

```sh
% cd $(mktemp -d)
% cabal update && cabal new-install --lib parallel
... snipped output ...
% cat <<EOF > parallel.hs
module P where
import Control.Parallel
EOF
% ghc -c parallel.hs
Loaded package environment from /home/tommd/.ghc/x86_64-linux-8.6.4/environments/default
% ls parallel.o parallel.hi
parallel.hi  parallel.o
```